# setting interpretor for python in visual studio code on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up python on my mac (as a first time user). The problem i encounter is that my interpreter is `Python 3.11.4`. But in my terminal the python version is only Python `3.9.13`. How can i change this?

Because of this issue i am unable to install any library. I get this is the VS code terminal:

```
(base) dana@Danas-Air Python % pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.25.1)
```

But when i try to load the library, i get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

This might have an obvious solution, but i havent been able to find it anywhere. I also looked into the setting and made sure that the box saying “Activate Python Environment in Terminal created using the Extension” is unchecked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be several different versions of **python** environments on your machine.

> But when i try to load the library, i get an error:
>
> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
> ```

The picture shows that your `numpy` is installed in the **python 310** environment, but you are currently using the ***python 311*** interpreter. Apparently there is no `numpy` in ***python 311***. You can install `numpy` on ***python 311*** or switch to **python 310** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`).

[image]

Then explain why the version displayed by the terminal is different from that displayed by vscode, because vscode uses the computer terminal as an integrated terminal, so when you type python in the terminal, it will use the one configured in the environment variable `path`. And the python version displayed in the lower right corner of vscode is the interpreter you choose for the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension.

*If you choose a virtual environment for vscode, the new terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>) will automatically activate the environment*

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments*
- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics*

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using anaconda as a virtual environment. VSCode uses the OS's Python by default. In order for VSCode to use the correct Python interpreter, the command palette must be called up via F1 and the correct interpreter can be referred to with "Python Select interpreter".

Another way to set the interpreter is clicking the python Version on the bottom left side in VSCode
[image]

By pressing the Python Version (here 3.8.10 64-bit) you can choose another Interpreter path

#### Disable conda at default Startup

VSCode Terminal often use the default conda environment. To disable this, run following command in VSCode Terminal

```bash
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

#### Control your Python Interpreter and pip installation location

check your python interpreter and pip path

```bash
which python3
which pip
```

Try to install new packages with the pip from your default python interpreter you use with:

```bash
python3 -m pip install PACKAGE
```

Comment: means i am using anaconda virtual environemt in VS code? How can i change the virtual environment? the command pallette is called using shift+cmd+P as far as i know :). I also in the last screen shot you can see that i have changed the interpreter in vscode to 3.11, but i do not know how to change the interpreter in terminal

Comment: What is the output of `which python`? Did you tried to install packages from the "normal" terminal with pip?

Comment: /Users/dana/opt/anaconda3/bin/python. In normal terminal i still have Python 3.9, so i didnt try it there. I only installed it with pip in the terminal in VScode

Comment: So you use in VSCode Terminal an anaconda Terminal and in your OS Terminal you use your default Python. Which Terminal do you set in VSCode? Have a look in your VSCode settings under `Settings -> Terminal -> Integrated -> Default Profile`


Also run following command in the VSCode Terminal
`conda config --set auto_activate_base False`

Comment: i am not aware of having changed any settings there, since i dont know the difference, so i assume it should be the "factory setting". i went to the setting and found only: Terminal › Integrated › Default Profile: Osx
The default terminal profile on macOS.

Comment: Did the conda command helped? ive it a try and start a new terminal in VSCode. Let me know if this fixed your problem

Comment: well, i am getting "python not found" now, i guess that was not the goal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254538/discussion-between-millerluki-and-nneka).